# rails + psql with structure dump uses PROCEDURE over FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql

Every time I dump my structure.sql on a rails app, I get PROCEDURE over FUNCTION. FUNCTION is our default and I have to commit the file in parts which is annoying and sometimes I miss lines which is even worse, as it is a rather big structure.sql file.

git diff example:

```
-CREATE TRIGGER cache_comments_count AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON public.comments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.update_comments_counter();
+CREATE TRIGGER cache_comments_count AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON public.comments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION public.update_comments_counter();
```

I'm sure there is a postgresql setting for this somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: none of my colleagues have this issue though

Comment: It's highly likely Rails uses `pg_get_triggerdef()` which changed what it returns with Postgres 12.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use Function or Procedure you get exactly the same. The documentation shows

```
CREATE [ CONSTRAINT ] TRIGGER name... 
    EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )
```

This means you can use either term FUNCTION or PROCEDURE but either way *function_name* is always called. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/pm6Mjz-N). For demo I have separate triggers for `insert` and `update`. Insert using `execute procedure` and update using `execute function`. This cannot be changed in Postgres it would have to be Rails setting. **NOTE:** Prior to v11 Postgres only allowed *execute procedure* even though you had to create a trigger `function` that was called.

Comment: If it was a rails setting would not the entire engineering team be on the same page? Unless I have some super rails config somewhere, but I searched my dotfiles, where else could this be?

Answer (score 0):

The function `pg_get_triggerdef()` changed between Postgres 11 and 12 when Postgres introduced real procedures. Since Postgres 12 it always returns a syntax that uses `EXECUTE FUNCTION` as in reality it **is** a function that is called when the trigger fires, not a procedure.

So this code:

```
create table t1 (id int);

create function trg_func()
returns trigger
as
$$
begin
return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger test_trigger
  before insert or update 
  on t1
  for each row
  execute procedure trg_func();

select pg_get_triggerdef(oid)
from pg_trigger 
where tgname = 'test_trigger';
```

returns the following in Postgres 11 and earlier:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.t1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_func()
```

and the following in Postgres 12 and later:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.t1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_func()
```

I guess Rails uses `pg_get_triggerdef()` to obtain the trigger source. So there is nothing you can do. If you want a consistent result, you should use the same Postgres version everywhere.

The column `action_statement` in the view `information_schema.triggers` also reflects the change in naming.

- [Postgres 11 example](https://dbfiddle.uk/fCNIGxma)
- [Postgres 12 example](https://dbfiddle.uk/LasPE8Q_)

Comment: I did a quick grep for that `pg_get_triggerdef` in rails and the pg gem, there we're no results. I will have to dig though the source to figure out what it is using.

Comment: @ChrisCPO: maybe it's using the column `action_statement` from `information_schema.triggers`.